# Two rows of divs floating right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I am working on a responsive web design that positions divs floated right, but in two rows.
Once the container div becomes two narrow, the tile divs will move down to form a new row.

For example

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>


.tile {
    height:96px;
    width:96px;
 }
```

Would display three divs in the first row, and two more in a row under the first row.

If the page is re-sized and the container becomes two narrow for the first row, div tiles should move to form a new row.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to nest the first 3 divs and the second 2 divs. You also need to 'divide' these 2 divs, so they build 2 rows (done with `css:clear`)  in order to achieve what you pretend:

html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="firstrow">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>

<div class="clear"></div>

   <div class="secondrow">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tile {
    height:96px;
    width:96px;
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
.clear{clear:both;}
```

see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/R59Qe/1/

Comment: I have tried that same solution, and is close to what I'm trying to accomplish. The only issue is supporting more or less than five tiles. I"m trying to find way to have the tiles condense further. For example, with your code, but four tiles in the first row and three in the second, when the container is re-sized to a width than can only contain three tiles in width, the grouping forms one row of three tiles, a row of one and one final row of three. The end result should have two rows of three and the seventh tile at the bottom in its own row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for this?

```
.tile {
    height:96px;
    width:96px;
    float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add "float:left" property to your class="tile", otherwise it will just render all div one below other.

Thanks.